# Linear Optimization: Objective function value, basic feasible solutions and reduced cost

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

For the system $$Ax=b, x \geq 0$$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m \leq n$, we call a set $B \subseteq \{1, \dotsc, n\}$, $|B|=m$ a basis for $A$, if $A_B$ is invertible, where $A_B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is the matrix $A$ where only columns according to the indices in $B$ are selected. We use $N=\{1, \dotsc, n\} \setminus B$.

In general, we use the index $B$ to denote that we only take the indices from $B$, and the same with $N$.

A basic feasible solution is defined as $x=(x_B, x_N)$ where $x_B=A_B^{-1} b$, and $x_N=0$.

We then want to compute the objective function value $c^T x$.

In my notes there is written

$$c^Tx=c_B^T x_B + c_N^T x_N.$$

This is clear, as far. But then, I thought that we have $x_B=A_B^{-1} b$, but in the notes it is written

$$c_B^Tx_B=c_B^T(A_B^{-1} b - A_B^{-1} A_N x_N).$$

Could you explain me why this is the case? So I see that $x_N$ is 0 anyways, so it should not be a problem to add this additional term, but why should we do this? Couldn't we omit all with $x_N$ and just state $c^T x = c_B^T x_B=c_B^T A_B^{-1}b$? Or do I make a mistake here?

And it gets even worse. I thought that a basic feasible solution is characterized by having the form $x=(x_B, x_N)$ as described above and satisfies $Ax=b$.

But now I read that $\xi$ satisfies $A\xi = b$ if and only if $\xi=(A_B^{-1} b - A_B^{-1}A_N \xi_N , \xi_N)$. So why are we interested in $x$ if $x$ does not solve $Ax=b$, and why is it called a basic feasible solution then?

This is where we can derive the definition of reduced cost from, so it seems to be really important.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $Ax = b$.  Partitioning $x = (x_B, x_N)$ and $A = (A_B, A_N)$, you get.
$$
\begin{align*}
A_B x_B + A_N x_N &= b \\
A_B x_B &= b - A_N x_N \\
A^{-1}_B A_B x_B &= A^{-1}_B (b - A_N x_N) \\
x_B &= A^{-1}_B b - A^{-1}_B A_N x_N
\end{align*}
$$
The final equation shows how $x_B$ can be expressed in terms of $x_N$.  That equation holds for any values of $x$ satisfying $Ax = b$, not just a basic feasible solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.